# Testing a method with RSpec? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My question is I have a module which is going back to a controller and I want to test it with RSpec but its not a class / there is no class inside the module its just a method so how would I test for example the methods return values , here is what I currently have in my module,

```
require 'rspec'

module LeagueModule
  module ScrapeProPlayers

    def scrape
      players = []
      return players
    end

  end
end

describe LeagueModule::ScrapeProPlayers do
  it "Check for any pro players" do
     host = Object.new.extend(LeagueModule::ScrapeProPlayers)
     host.scrape.should == 0

  end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? Is it working? If not, what's the error?

Comment: when I run the test it just says one failed example but it should be passing

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out this firstly I shouldn't of been using 'should' its better to use 'expect' and that was the wrong way of writing it :

```
describe LeagueModule::ScrapeProPlayers do
  it "Check for any pro players" do
     host = Object.new.extend(LeagueModule::ScrapeProPlayers)
     result = host.scrape
     expect(result.length).to eq(0)
  end
end
```